# Use 'includes' models inside SQL Rails queries

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have model `Task` which has relation to users table - as asignee and reporter

```
class Task < ActiveRecord
  belongs_to :assignee, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :reporter, class_name: 'User'
end
```

In sql I want to select Task where assignee has specific name

```
Task.includes(:assignee, :reporter).where('assignee.first_name = ?', 'Filip')
```

but this query raises:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "assignee"
```

I can call

`Task.includes(:assignee, :reporter).where('user.first_name = ?', 'Filip')`
but it returns records from both assignee and reporter

How to add condition in where clause only referencing assignee relation?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the `model: 'User'` option? I would assume it should have been `class_name: 'User'`, but may be I'm missing something

Comment: @AndreyDeineko good catch, I meant class_name. I was writing this example by hand :)

Answer (score 0):

If `Assignee's` table name is `assignees`, You can write this way:

```
    Task.
      includes(:assignee, :reporter).
      where('assignees.first_name = ?','Filip').
      references(:users)
```

Hope to help you.